# Personalization in Android App (Beginner)

Tags: android, sql

I am new at Android. And I have to design an app where user can input his/her own profile in the app. What i would like to happen is that after the user install the app, the user will be redirected to the **ProfileActivityUI** to input his/her profile. After that, he/she will be redirected to **MainMenuActivityUI** of the app.

My problem is that after user input his/her profile info on the app and that when he/she close the app and start the app again, he/she will be redirected to **ProfileActivityUI** again (in which he/she shouldn't be cause he/she already inputted his/her profile). It should that the user will be redirected to **MainMenuActivityUI**.

**ProfileActivityUI** should appear one time only. and that is after installation. But when the user open the app again. it shouldn't appear anymore.

I need your help. cause i dont know how to do that. Sample codes are appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

hey you need to implement share preference:-
1) on ProfileActivityUI you need to check share preference on load,

```
SharedPreferences sref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


        sref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sref.edit();
        String checkstring = sref.getString("RoleID",null);
    if(!checkstring==null)
        {
             Intent i = new intent (this,MainMenuActivityUI.class)
             startactivity(i);
        }
```

2)when you ProfileActivityUI is submint successfully then right down this code:-

```
     SharedPreferences sref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


        sref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sref.edit();
    editor.putString("RoleID", RoleID);
    editor.commit();

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainMenuActivityUI.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

then you get what you want 100%

Comment: I actually don't understand that code except the INTENT part.

Answer (score 0):

**you should try it with sharedpreferences .**

```
public class ProfileActivityUI extends Activity {



    SharedPreferences srefforsignout,sref;
    Editor edtr;
    int signoutcod;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        sref=getSharedPreferences("SignOut", MODE_PRIVATE);     
        signoutcod=sre.getInt("signoutcode", 0);

        if(signoutcod==1){

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenuActivityUI.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }


      srefforsignout=getSharedPreferences("SignOut", MODE_PRIVATE);
        edtr=srefforsignout.edit();


        buttonsignin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent i=new Intent(ProfileActivityUI.this,MainMenuActivityUI.class);

                    edtr.putInt("signoutcode", 1);                          
                    edtr.commit();

                    startActivity(i);


        });
       }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `SharedPreferences` will solve your problem try to do this.

First of all make a start up screen (Splash screen) so you can check in background that is user registered or not.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

Thread td;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
String name, pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    td = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                td.sleep(3000);
                SharedPreferences sharepPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                            MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //Make sure You have entered same key in my case "email" or "password"..
                name = sharepPreferences.getString("email", null);
                pass = sharepPreferences.getString("password", null);
                if (name == null) {
                    if (pass == null) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                    ProfileActivityUI.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                                MainMenuActivityUI.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }
                finish();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    td.start();
}
```

Now Whenever user starts your application after installing it, there will be no data in shared preference, so it will be redirected to **ProfileActivityUI**.
Now in **ProfileActivityUI** you have to save data which user has entered in `SharedPreferences`.

Do this in your **ProfileActivityUI**

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";` //Make sure this is same in both activity.

`sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();`

`editor.putString("username", et1.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", et4.getText().toString());
editor.commit();`

This will Store your data permanently.
Now if you open your Application again it will redirect you to the **ProfileActivityUI** straight after splash screen.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is to start in the MainMenuActivityUI and if the profile it's not saved , automatically redirects him to the ProfileActivityUI.
If the UI it's not very complicated you always can make a setContentView for one or the other view (but it's kind of messy thing...)